# Prefilling tags when linking from an external site

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, hyperlinks

I can see/predict some developer-oriented sites starting to use StackOverflow as their forum, instead of maintaining their own forum. I think it would be beneficial to both parties.

They can integrate Stack Overflow content in their site with tag-specific RSS feeds, and direct people to SO to ask questions.

To link people to ask questions, they can just link to stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. But it would be even more beneficial if they could prefill tags with their site moniker, e.g stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=php,mysql,mysite.com.

Is this something worth considering? (both the feature of prefilling tags, and the wider context of use as a plugin to another site) Has there been previous discussion about this? Would SO find this beneficial? Or is it a bad idea and SO is mostly interested in "direct" traffic and not serving third-party sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO isn't an advertising platform, it's a place to get answers and discuss programming related issues. Being able to post remotely is one thing (hopefully something that will be accomplished in a few months by an API), but there's no place for tags that refer to where a user came from.

This is along the same lines as greetings, signatures, and closing statements and is completely unnecessary. I don't care if you came from icantcode.com, I'll answer your question if I can. If this behavior is ever executed you can kiss any usefulness of SO goodbye, as it will become an advertising haven for wehaveawebsitewithaterribleenginesoweusestackoverflowsinsteadbutstillwanttodirecttraffictooursite.com
It will also cause the unwanted behaviour of bias towards questions with certain tags that have nothing to do with the actual problem.

> I only want to answer questions with
>   the tag mysite.com to help out my
>   users

Which is against everything that SO is about.

Answer (score 6):

This has been implemented at some point.

You can now pre-fill the tag field with a link by passing a `tags` parameter, like so:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?**tags=javascript+jquery**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=javascript+jquery)

Answer (score -3):

This is something I'd like to see so that people can ask question on my blog that I can then easily find.

Comment: -1 Your profile is more then enough requirement for people to read your blog. SO is about the community, not personal justification.

Comment: I can appreciate you wanting to promote your blog, and you and your blog are obviously not spammy in nature. However, on Stack Overflow you have 20k rep, nearly a million people reached, and nearly 3.5 thousand profile views. I see no need to also include your site link in answers. If all users started doing the same then the sites would look awful and very spammy. This is why there are also no signatures here, to keep answers clean and about the info :)